# Access Full-Page zoom setting with javascript in Safari 5?

Tags: javascript, dom, safari, webkit

Is there a way to programmatically access a page's current zoom-level in javascript with Safari 5? I'd like to access it with a Safari extension, but I'm coming up empty in the documentation. I'd also be interested in any other creative ways to mimic full-page zoom (maybe with CSS?) that could be done with the new extension system in Safari 5. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this stackoverflow answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers/5078596#5078596